# EAR-Project where to place properties-Files used by EJB-Project using Glassfish3.1.2 with Java EE6

Tags: eclipse, classloader, java-ee-6, ear

i got a problem with my .properties-files in an EAR project.
I already checked some topics on this issue at svf as well as on other boards.

I use properties file for a Util in my EJB-Project, but i can't access them.
Refering to a post in a jboss-forum i already tried to put them under META-INF in the EAR-Project and EarContent/lib/classes/ .. sadly it didn't work.
I still get this error:

> SEVERE: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base
>   name credentials, locale en_US    at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
>     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:724)  at
>   com.lumen.Utils.PropsUtil.loadProperties(PropsUtil.java:50)

I try do access the props-file via: 
Line 50:
 `ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("credentials");`

My Project Structure looks like this:

**EAR**

->EarContent

-->lib

---> someexternallibs.jar

--->classes

---->*.properties

->META-INF

-->*.properties

-->application.xml

**EJB**

->src

-->package.package.Util <-- here i need to load the properties

Web <-- Here i don't need the properties at all

->src

->WebContent

Add Info: I use eclipse for development, the rest of the project is working so fine so far.

Hope you can help me :)

GreeZ ZuSe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `classes` folder is not allowed in a EAR structure.

So, firstly you should pack your resources in a jar file, either one already existing or a dedicated one in the lib folder.

Another issue arises regarding the classloader hierarchy if you use the simple:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(String)
```

The correct way to call classloader related methods in presence of multiple classloaders is by specifying the current *context* classloader as in:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundlename",Locale.getDefault(),Thread.currentThread.().getContextClassLoader())
```

Comment: can you show exactly how you were able to make it work? same problem here.

Comment: @Fritz  I uploaded an example on github: https://github.com/carlopellegriniarchijcom/ear-resource-sample

Comment: Hi @Carlo Pellegrini, do you have any idea if this solution is accordant to the EJB spec which prohibits accessing local files as I found out in this [discussion (Process files in Java EE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901138/process-files-in-java-ee/1903038)?