# EJB and internationalization (i18n)

Tags: internationalization, ejb

I am aware that according to the EJB spec one must not access files from within EJBs by using java.io.*.

In this SO answers [Process files in Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1903651) there are a couple of ways to bypass this restriction which all come with rather plenty of efforts. Anyway I do understand the reasons behind this design decision (i. e. scalability, clustering).

My question is, does that mean I can not use i18n-(property)-files within EJBs (which are bundled in the jar)?

Comment: The restriction for files doesn't apply to classpath resources such as i18n property files it concerns resources in the File System.

Comment: Hi @garfield. Glad to hear that. In a normal web project I access the resource bundles by declaring them in faces-config.xml. Do you know how I can access them in EJBs (is there an API)?